# How to include the file path in an IO error in Rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust

In this minimalist program, I'd like the `file_size` function to include the path `/not/there` in the `Err` so it can be displayed in the `main` function:

```
use std::fs::metadata;
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn file_size(path: &Path) -> io::Result<u64> {
    Ok(metadata(path)?.len())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = file_size(&PathBuf::from("/not/there")) {
        eprintln!("{}", err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not all IO errors *have* a path associated (or even deal with a filesystem to start with!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must define your own error type in order to wrap this additional data.

Personally, I like to use the [custom_error](https://docs.rs/custom_error/latest/custom_error/macro.custom_error.html) crate for that, as it's especially convenient for dealing with several types. In your case it might look like this:

```
use custom_error::custom_error;
use std::fs::metadata;
use std::io;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::result::Result;

custom_error! {ProgramError
    Io {
        source: io::Error,
        path: PathBuf
    } = @{format!("{path}: {source}", source=source, path=path.display())},
}

fn file_size(path: &Path) -> Result<u64, ProgramError> {
    metadata(path)
        .map(|md| md.len())
        .map_err(|e| ProgramError::Io {
            source: e,
            path: path.to_path_buf(),
        })
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = file_size(&PathBuf::from("/not/there")) {
        eprintln!("{}", err);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/not/there: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Comment: It looks quite good — I only had to change `"IO Error"` to `"{path}: {source}"` in order to have a more user friendly message when using `eprintln!("{}", err);`.
I must say I was hoping something simpler / less verbose, especially to convert the IO error to the custom error.

Comment: This is the less verbose version. Try the same without a crate like custom_error or failure. Note that custom_error makes it easier to deal with several error types when you don't add data but just wrap the source error: https://docs.rs/custom_error/latest/custom_error/macro.custom_error.html#automatic-conversion-from-other-error-types

Comment: I also think I'd store the path as a `PathBuf` instead of eagerly performing the lossy transformation.

Comment: Using a `PathBuf` in the error is a bit more work, because the `custom_error!` macro generates some code that tries to use `to_string()` on the path, but this method is not available there.

Comment: the updated code is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/glehmann/72e0acd5c176e6a3d532433b0d671e61

Comment: @GaëtanLehmann your updated code looks good. I'd suggest you edit my answer (but be wary that changing the argument passed to `file_size` is changing the question too)

Comment: After scratching my head a bit on that problem, I think what I'd really like to have is just `Ok(metadata(path).with_path(path)?.len())`, `with_path` being equivalent to a call to `map_err` to convert the error to a new type, but much less verbose…

Comment: @GaëtanLehmann I modified my answer to use map and map_err instead of match. But I'd advise against hiding the err transformation more: I see no reason to make it look like magic, this is an important part of the logic

Comment: I doubt that I can do anything to make err transformation look more like magic than the `From` transformation performed by the `?` operator.
For now, I ended with a function that does the transformation, and that I call in `map_err`: https://github.com/glehmann/hld/commit/4865b461cc73f57b3c6d1b15c1927270b7373f3f#diff-0c20ef37727d2015fb136ac1092cd3f3R46

Comment: Oh, hard link deduplication... looks a little like what I just did: https://github.com/Canop/broot/blob/master/src/file_sizes.rs#L23

Comment: as this is getting verbose: There's a rust chat room on SO: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust

Comment: I've implemented a new trait on `io::Result` to add the `with_path` method: https://gist.github.com/glehmann/b261e7aa22bd01f70501883d97b2f6bd — works great :)

Answer (score 3):

While [Denys Séguret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935077/155423) is correct, I like using my crate [SNAFU](https://crates.io/crates/snafu) because it provides the concept of a [context](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.2.3/snafu/trait.ResultExt.html#tymethod.context). This makes the act of attaching the path (or anything else!) very easy to do:

```
use snafu::{ResultExt, Snafu}; // 0.2.3
use std::{
    fs, io,
    path::{Path, PathBuf},
};

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum ProgramError {
    #[snafu(display("Could not get metadata for {}: {}", path.display(), source))]
    Metadata { source: io::Error, path: PathBuf },
}

fn file_size(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Result<u64, ProgramError> {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    let md = fs::metadata(&path).context(Metadata { path })?;
    Ok(md.len())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = file_size("/not/there") {
        eprintln!("{}", err);
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice way to do it too, and it more closely match the `with_path` method I was proposing. I'll give it a try!